# ListView - Binding listviewitem data to an object

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listview

Let's assume I have the following ListView:

```
<ListView Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="IsTrue" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsTrue}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And the following Test class I want to bind:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(Boolean IsTrue, string name)
    {
        this.IsTrue = IsTrue;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean IsTrue { get; set; }
    public string name { get; private set; }
}
```

Here's the command I use to add ListViewItem:

```
Test a = new Test(false, "a");
listView.Items.Add(a);
```

Now when I try to change the a object IsTrue value the value IsTrue on ListView won't update. Why is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var e = PropertyChanged;
        if (e != null)
            e(this, args);
    }

    private bool isTrue;
    public Boolean IsTrue
    {
        get { return isTrue; }
        set
        {
            if (isTrue == value)
                return;
            isTrue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTrue"));
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Test(Boolean isTrue, string name)
    {
        this.isTrue = isTrue;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface for class `Test`, so when you change the Property, the UI will get notified.